# Can't fetch an item out of weird json content

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to get some items from json content. However, the structure of that json content is foreign to me and as a result I can't fetch the value of `property` out of it.

I've tried so far with:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/5958-SW-4th-St-Miami-FL-33144/43835884_zpid/'

def fetch_content(link):
    content = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one("script#hdpApolloPreloadedData").text
    print(json.loads(item)['apiCache'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetch_content(link)
```

The result I get running the above script is:

```
{"VariantQuery{\"zpid\":43835884}":{"property":{"zpid":43835884,"streetAddress":"5958 SW 4th St",
```

Which I can't further process for that weird key in front.

Expected output:

```
{"zpid":43835884,"streetAddress":"5958 SW 4th St", ----
```

How can I get the value of that property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get zpid and address by their mangled json with:

```
json.loads(json.loads(item.text)['apiCache'])['VariantQuery{"zpid":43835884}']['property']['zpid']                                                                                  
Out[1889]: 43835884

json.loads(json.loads(item.text)['apiCache'])['VariantQuery{"zpid":43835884}']['property']['streetAddress']                                                                         
Out[1890]: '5958 SW 4th St'
```

I noticed you can always get the zpid like this:

```
link = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/5958-SW-4th-St-Miami-FL-33144/43835884_zpid/'
content = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text,"lxml")
item = soup.select_one("script#hdpApolloPreloadedData").text
print(json.loads(item)['zpid'])
```

Comment: It works for now but any identical url having different `zpid` will definitely fail, as in `https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/907-24th-Ave-Seattle-WA-98122/48674590_zpid/`.

Comment: @robots.txt  zpid always seems to work as an attribute, i updated with that

Comment: No way. You are incredible @oppressionslayer. Thanks.

Comment: One small question - how can I format this to reuse the zpid. I tried with `item = ['VariantQuery{"zpid":f"{_zpid}"}']` where `_zpid` is `123456`. However, it turned out to be a wrong formatting. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean like this? f'''VariantQuery{{"zpid":"{_zpid}"}}'''    to use {}''s without a variable, you have to double them.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your function to the following. I also added another function (`process_fetched_content()`) to give you some more freedom. You could simply run it and it will take care of situations even when you have multiple keys that start with `'VariantQuery{"zpid":'`. The final output is a `dict` with the keys being your `zpid` and the values being what you are looking for.

If you have a lot of zpid values, then this will let you accumulate them all together and then process them. The benefit is the list of keys is then the list of zpids you have.

> Here's how you could use this code.

```
results = process_fetched_content(raw_dictionary = fetch_content(link, verbose=False))
print(results)
```

**output**:

```
{'43835884': {'zpid': 43835884, 'streetAddress': '5958 SW 4th St', 'zipcode': '33144', 'city': 'Miami', 'state': 'FL', 'latitude': 25.76661, 'longitude': -80.292801, 'price': 340000, 'dateSold': 1576875600000, 'bathrooms': 2, 'bedrooms': 3, 'livingArea': 1757, 'yearBuilt': 1973, 'lotSize': 4331, 'homeType': 'SINGLE_FAMILY', 'homeStatus': 'RECENTLY_SOLD', 'photoCount': 19, 'imageLink': 'https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_g/IS7yxihwtuqmlq1000000000.jpg', 'daysOnZillow': 0, 'isFeatured': False, 'shouldHighlight': False, 'brokerId': 0, 'zestimate': 341336, 'rentZestimate': 2200, 'listing_sub_type': {}, 'priceReduction': '', 'isUnmappable': False, 'rentalPetsFlags': 128, 'mediumImageLink': 'https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_c/IS7yxihwtuqmlq1000000000.jpg', 'isPreforeclosureAuction': False, 'homeStatusForHDP': 'RECENTLY_SOLD', 'priceForHDP': 340000, 'festimate': 341336, 'isListingOwnedByCurrentSignedInAgent': False, 'isListingClaimedByCurrentSignedInUser': False, 'hiResImageLink': 'https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_f/IS7yxihwtuqmlq1000000000.jpg', 'watchImageLink': 'https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_j/IS7yxihwtuqmlq1000000000.jpg', 'tvImageLink': 'https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_m/IS7yxihwtuqmlq1000000000.jpg', 'tvCollectionImageLink': 'https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_l/IS7yxihwtuqmlq1000000000.jpg', 'tvHighResImageLink': 'https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_n/IS7yxihwtuqmlq1000000000.jpg', 'zillowHasRightsToImages': True, 'desktopWebHdpImageLink': 'https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_h/IS7yxihwtuqmlq1000000000.jpg', 'isNonOwnerOccupied': False, 'hideZestimate': False, 'isPremierBuilder': False, 'isZillowOwned': False, 'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'USA', 'taxAssessedValue': 224131, 'streetAddressOnly': '5958 SW 4th St', 'unit': ' '}}
```

## Code

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/5958-SW-4th-St-Miami-FL-33144/43835884_zpid/'

def fetch_content(link, verbose=False):
    content = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one("script#hdpApolloPreloadedData").text
    d = json.loads(item)['apiCache']
    d = json.loads(d)
    if verbose:
        print(d)
    return d

def process_fetched_content(raw_dictionary=None):
    if raw_dictionary is not None:
        keys = [k for k in raw_dictionary.keys() if k.startswith('VariantQuery{"zpid":')]
        results = dict((k.split(':')[-1].replace('}',''), d.get(k).get('property', None)) for k in keys)
        return results
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: I didn't have any option yet to run your script. I'll let you know once I execute it. Thanks.